# fibonacci diamond shape pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def fib(f, N):
    f[1] = 0
    f[2] = 1
    for i in range(3, N + 1):
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]

def fiboTriangle(n):
    N = n * (n + 1) // 2
    f = [0]*(N + 1)
    fib(f, N)
    fiboNum = 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n-i):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(i):
            print(f[fiboNum], end=" ")
            fiboNum+=1
        print()
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        for j in range(n-i):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(i):
            print(f[fiboNum], end=" ")
            fiboNum+=1
        print()        
n = 3
fiboTriangle(n)
```

this is my code i get this output:
0
1 1
2 3 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ali/Python/emipro.py", line 38, in 
fiboTriangle(n)
File "/home/ali/Python/emipro.py", line 34, in fiboTriangle
print(f[fiboNum], end=" ")
IndexError: list index out of range
but i want
diamond shape pattern in output

Comment: what do you mean "i want diamond shape pattern in output" ?

Answer (score 0):

After receiving your comment I went back to reviewing the type of numbers you were attempting to create in a diamond format.  I got a diamond with the numeric sequence you noted by changing:

```
N = n * (n + 1) // 2
```

to:

```
N = n * (n + 1)
```

Here is the full code.

```
def fib(f, N):
    f[1] = 0
    f[2] = 1
    for i in range(3, N):
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]

def fiboTriangle(n):
    N = n * (n + 1)     # Changed this equation
    f = [0]*(N + 1)
    fib(f, N)
    fiboNum = 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n-i):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(i):
            print(f[fiboNum], end=" ")
            fiboNum+=1
        print()
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        for j in range(n-i):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(i):
            print(f[fiboNum], end=" ")
            fiboNum+=1
        print()        
n = 3
fiboTriangle(n)
```

That produced the following diamond.

```
craig@Una:~/Python_Programs/Fibonacci$ python3 Fibonacci.py 
   
  0 
 1 1 
2 3 5 
 8 13 
  21
```

Give that a try.